# bootstrap ui modal.open error:Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Im trying to make my first modal using Angularjs. I'm not sure or why I'm getting this error. I have error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
```

Here is my code:
Layout:

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-resource.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ng-grid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <script src="~/Scripts/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/ng-grid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />


</head>
<body ng-controller="CtrlController">
            @RenderBody()                 
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("app", ["ngGrid", "ui.bootstrap"]);
    app.controller("CtrlController", function ($scope, $http, $log, $modal) {




        $scope.on = function ($modal) {
            alert("dddd");
            $modal.open(
                {
                    templateUrl: 'http://localhost:58652/Home/TestView',
                    controller: "CtrlController"

                }
            );
        }
    });




})()
```

HTML for button:

```
<div ng-click="on()" class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
</div>
<button ng-click="on()" type=button class="btn">Добавить</button>
```

But when I click the button, I get the error Cannot read property 'open' of undefined. Why is that?

Comment: Can you show HTML for button?

Comment: $scope.on is some function you are calling en the view?, why are you passing $modal as the first argument?, this $modal var is "blinding" the other $modal var you are inyecting into the controller

Comment: Some comments on your code: Without the complete code it's hard to help you out of this one. You don't even tell us the versions of most of the libraries you use. Furthermore the mixture of js-libs looks frightening to me ;). Why for Angulars sake do you import bootstrap.js and ui-bootstrap.js ?   I know it's cumbersome, but if you still got problems and I also really don't love the following comment, but... could you provide a plunker for this one?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$modal` parameter from `$scope.on` function definition and it should work. You don't have to pass it with `ngClick` wince you already have `$modal` service in scope:

```
$scope.on = function() {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'http://localhost:58652/Home/TestView',
        controller: "CtrlController"
    });
};
```

Comment: when I removed $model ,there was error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Denis what about the templateUrl is that reachable.  Also what about your controller I think that needs to include $modalInstance in the params of the controller